# CSS Location possibilities in pages

Tags: html, css

I know that you can have CSS on External Files, using a `<style>` tag on the page `<head>` and inline using `style="something here">`

My question is... is it allowed the have a  tag with styles in the `<body>` or just the `<head>` ?

Comment: You have HTML in your question, which makes for a cryptic result. I think though that you are asking if it is allowed to have a `<style>` element in the body. And then the answer is: not officially, no, but most browsers don't care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is allowed, and it applies to the whole page.  It's just not encouraged.

It's wise to load the stylesheet very quickly so that content is styled when it appears on the screen.  This is called a [flash of unstyled content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) and putting the `<style>` tag in the head where it's one of the first things parsed by the browser usually avoids it.

But, for example, if you wanted to embed a `<style>` tag on a page whose content you got from an ajax request, it would take visual effect immediately no matter where it was placed.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Alex, by putting the style in an external style sheet or by putting in the head is the best way.

Also on inline styles:
  They aren't recommended because the whole point of style sheets is to separate the format and styling, to make it easier to edit in the future

A link to talk you through external css ->
http://www.tizag.com/cssT/external.php